# NVIDIA graphic drivers elementary os 6

Tags: nvidia

I need to install NVIDIA drivers on my pc. How can I do?
I tried """software-properties-gtk""" but I have an infinite loop login.
I discovered that my driver needs a kernel that works only on Ubuntu 16.04 and before.
Since I love elementary os, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`